# iOS 7 Keyboard - Key enter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, keyboard, key

I wonder if there is how I change the text or image of key return the keyboard for any text or message. How make?

For example:

[Image Keyboard Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Vv3.png)

On the Key "Search" (or "Done", "Return", "Go") replace to symbol enter or text "Enter".

I thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant change text on the return key . But you can select one of the return key from predefine enum :

```
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];
```

enum is :

```
typedef enum {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

Comment: I believed it was possible. Thank you